# Is it possible to output the last added/modified text in a file in the last hour?

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I am using CronTab to schedule sending e-mails hourly with the latest logged errors in a logged file debug.log

So far I managed to set CronTab to send an e-mail with the last 5 logged errors (using a shell script). The thing is that I don't want the same errors to be sent: If an error has been sent at 12 pm , I don't want it to be sent again at 1 pm if it is among those 5.

Note: I used 5 as a random number. It was to test to see if I can do this. But I need help with what I previously mentioned.

I don't need to know how to send the e-mail and all that. All I need is to know how to output the errors logged in the file in the last hour.

Comment: Assuming your log file has a timestamp on it's entries, adjust your script to only pull new entries since the last run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using command below

> tail -f debug.log | grep 'ERROR_INDICATOR' >> error.log

and then modify your crontab job script to delete the content of the error.log right after you send the email.

Comment: what is 'ERROR_INDICATOR' ? I couldn't find what it means and does? Also, where does it specify it needs to be the logs from the last hour?

Comment: "ERROR_INDICATOR" is just an example.  Not all the lines logged in log files are errors.  If you just want the last few lines and do not need to filter, then omit the grep

Comment: but this does not output the errors from the last hour

Comment: Can you put several sample lines of your debug.log in your question above?